# How to select nodes by attribute that starts with... in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml document and I want to select nodes by attribute that starts with '/employees/'.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/employees/1.html" title="Employee 1">Employee 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>Robert</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/employees/2.html" title="Employee 2">Employee 2</a>
    </td>
    <td>Jennifer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So in C#, I would do something like this:

```
parentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/th/a[@href='/employees/.....']")
```

Is this possible with C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use Linq to Xml? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simple `starts-with` function does what you need:

```
parentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td/a[starts-with(@href, '/employees/')]")
```

Answer (score 3):

using pure `LINQ` you can do something like this

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("YOUR_XML_STRING");
var anchors = from e in doc. Descendants("a") where e.Attribute("href").Value.StartsWith("/employee/") select e;
```

// now you can seelect any node by doing a combination of .Parent.Parent.....

Answer (score 1):

So, something like this?

```
var xml = @"<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href=""/employees/1.html"" title=""Employee 1"">Employee 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>Robert</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href=""/employees/2.html"" title=""Employee 2"">Employee 2</a>
    </td>
    <td>Jennifer</td>
  </tr>
</table>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var employees = doc.SelectNodes("/table/tr/td/a[starts-with(@href, '/employees/')]");
DoWhatever(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can load your XML into the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instance and use [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelements%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to search using your expression.